# Slope of a curve Matlab data point

Tags: matlab, plot

[Plots are here](http://s1300.photobucket.com/user/Vittal_Rao/library/)
I have plotted some current values with respect to time. What I am trying to find is the difference between peak current to the least current before peak and the time difference. So basically I want `di/dt` (i.e slope of the peak current curve). I have written code that finds peak current and time taken to reach from zero value( as shown below).

But I want the time taken from the least current value before the peak to the peak current. 
How can I achieve this in Matlab code?

```
 [r,c]=size(B);
    [M,l]=max(B,[],2); % store max values along rows and its indices in a column%
     dt=t(l)-t(1); %with indices of max time, dt is stored as a column
 display(dt);

%finding Peak current indices in a loop%
     for (i=1:r)
    di(i)=M(i)-B(i,1);  % difference between peak current and initial current   stored in di as row%
    end
    display(di);
    DI=di';                 %match column to column
     didt=DI./dt;            %divide di/dt
     display(didt);
```

I know the question may not be clear, please comment so i can clarify.

Comment: Since i have less than 10 reputation, i cannot post the picture of my plot

Comment: you can post a link to your image and someone will upload it for you :)

Comment: I am a bit confused here. May I ask what information you have about the current? Also, what is the scenario? What I mean is: is it some kind of electrical impulse (eg discharged capacitor) or more like measured current from a high power network?

Comment: It is actually the real time current values across 12 different coils, sampled over a time period of 1 seconds. The data is a raw matlab data with almost 16000 sets of time, data values.
My job is to find the time taken to reach peak(I max) current from the least current before it. That will given me highest di/dt

Comment: I'm still confused about what you are trying to do. Do you want to find the peak current **for each coil**, then the value of di/dt leading up to the peak **for that coil**?

Comment: If you see the plot i have uploaded in the link. I need the di/dt for the marked positions.